# Blank Page when "Print at Bottom of Page" is on and all sections on the blank page are suppressed

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using Crystal Reports Basic for Visual Studio 2008.

I have each item in a group printing on a separate page.  There is a footer section which is set to Print at the Bottom of the Page.  I am suppressing the page when its data is 0 by suppressing all sections with a formula.

The problem I have is that when the footer is set to bottom of the page, the suppressed page is printed as a blank page.  When I turn off bottom of the page, and use NewPageBefore with the formula instead, the page is suppressed correctly, but when I turn on "bottom of the page", I get a blank page.

I have checked for unsuppressed sections, but they are all either suppressed with the checkbox or the formula.

Comment: "When I turn **on** bottom of the page, and use NewPageBefore with the formula instead, the page is suppressed correctly" - do you mean, when you turn **off** bottom of the page, and use NewPageBefore with the formula instead, the page is suppressed correctly?

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue before, which took me quite a lot of time to find a workaround. Hopefully putting the answer here will save some time for others.

Whenever you enable "*Print at Bottom of Page*" for a section, make sure other sections that come after that (including Report Footer and Page Footer) are all **suppressed**, otherwise there will be an empty page printed at the end. Note that keeping them empty or ultimately narrow is not enough, they must be suppressed explicitly.

I had an empty report footer with a 0 height, and I thought it would take no space and will not cause an issue; but I was wrong. I had to explicitly suppress that footer to solve the issue.

If the sections coming after that are suppressed via a formula, make sure the formula is satisfied on the last record.

Comment: I had similar issues too, explicitly suppress the Page Footer and Report Footer solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I am a complete novice here, but I had to build a report for work and figure out how to do this.

I had the same issue - but caused by two separate reasons. First, when I checked the 'page after' to keep each group on its own page, I had a blank page at the end. I simply added a formula 'Not OnLastRecord'.

Then, the second issue was the 'print footer at bottom of page'  - I wanted each sub-group to start a new column at top of page. This also created a blank page at the end (if I turned off the 'print footer at bottom' the page disappeared). I followed Sina Irvanian's advide here and suppressed the footers that came after it. I only suppressed the ones that were blank since my page footer had content - this was sufficient.

Problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though NewPageBefore is unconditionally checked on the footer section. If so, try unchecking it and checking NewPageAfter instead.

Alternatively, if a new page has to be begun **before** the footer section which is then printed at the bottom of the following page when the data is not 0, try unchecking the NewPageBefore option and instead enter the **opposite** of the conditional suppress formula in the conditional NewPageBefore formula - ie. data is **not** 0.